# C# DataGridView Filter works but after using the Filter the selected row doesn't return the right data

Tags: c#, datagridview, rowfilter

I've taken over somebody's program.  So this is my first time dealing with DataViewGrid.

The data populates perfectly.  When the user select a row it populates a text box in the form.  Which I'm not sure how that part is working since there is nothing that says

```
txtEmail.text =
```

Or Selected Row anywhere in this form.  But it's ok.. if it works I'll deal.

Here's my issue.  I've added a filter. which works great.  As you type it filters each row for the matches.

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

     DataView dv = new DataView(this.dsFavoritesList.gryFavoritesList);
     dv.Sort = "Name ASC";

     dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'",txtSearch.Text);
     dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
}
```

But now as soon as you type anything in the filter, any row that is selected does not populate the textbox.  It isn't until I reload the entire form that I can select anything properly again.

If I'm beginning to understand... I've update the gridview but not the source.. I just don't know how.

Thanks!
-Matt

### **Whole Form**

### In the designer view I have 3 text boxes. txtEmail, txtName, txtImageCount that get populated as I make a new selection.  But once I filter the datagridview the boxes never get populated as I try to select rows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using Ini;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Threading;



namespace UpLoadImages
{
    public partial class CopyFavorites : Form
    {
        public CopyFavorites()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CopyFavorites_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // get the default values
            string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
            IniFile ini = new IniFile(string.Format(@"{0}\gift.ini", appPath));

            txtEventsDrive.Text = ini.IniReadValue("Info", "LocationOfEvents");
            txtHiResTarget.Text = ini.IniReadValue("Info", "FavWorkSpace");
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            oleDbConnection1.ConnectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];

            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            //commented out so we can try it as a background worker
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dsFavoritesList.gryFavoritesList' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            //this.gryFavoritesListTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsFavoritesList.gryFavoritesList);

            ProgressPanel.Visible = false;
            txtSearch.Focus();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.MdiParent.MainMenuStrip.Enabled = false;

        try
        {
            string strError = CopyImages();



            StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

            sql.AppendFormat("UPDATE FavoritesHeader SET FavoritesHeader.FilesCopied = {0} ", Convert.ToInt32(txtImagesCopied.Text));
            sql.AppendFormat("WHERE FavoritesHeader.EmailAddress='{0}'", txtEmail.Text);
            UpdateDatabase(sql.ToString());


            this.gryFavoritesListTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsFavoritesList.gryFavoritesList);


            MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
            MessageBox.Show(this, strError, "Copy Images", buttons, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

            ProgressPanel.Visible = false;
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.MdiParent.MainMenuStrip.Enabled = true;
        }




    }
    private string CopyAllImages()
    {
        StringBuilder strError = new StringBuilder();
        string clr = "\r\n";
        strError.AppendFormat("Time started: {0}{1}{1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), clr);
        try
        {


            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.AppendFormat("Select FavoritesHeader.EmailAddress,  StrConv([LastName],1)+'_'+StrConv([firstname],3) AS Folder, FavoritesDetail.ImagePath,MainEvents.MainEventCode, ");
            str.AppendFormat("FavoritesDetail.ImageName FROM (FavoritesHeader INNER JOIN MainEvents ON FavoritesHeader.MainEventID = MainEvents.MainEventID) ");
            str.AppendFormat("LEFT JOIN FavoritesDetail ON FavoritesHeader.FavoritesHeaderID = FavoritesDetail.FavoritesHeaderID ");
            str.AppendFormat(" WHERE (((MainEvents.isActive)=1)) ");
            str.AppendFormat(" ORDER BY FavoritesHeader.EmailAddress,  StrConv([LastName],1)+'_'+StrConv([firstname],3), FavoritesDetail.ImagePath");

            DataTable dt_Images = GetDataTable(str.ToString());
            int maxFiles = dt_Images.Rows.Count;

            strError.AppendFormat("Images to copy: {0}{1}{1}", maxFiles, clr);
            Application.DoEvents();


            progressBar.Maximum = maxFiles;
            progressBar.Value = 0;
            ProgressPanel.Visible = true;


            string strTarget = string.Empty;
            int i = 0;

            foreach (DataRow row in dt_Images.Rows)
            {
                i = i + 1;
                progressBar.Value = i;

                ProgressCount.Text = string.Format("Files Copied: {0} of {1}", i, maxFiles);
                Application.DoEvents();

                string path = row["ImagePath"] as string;
                path = path.Replace(@"Thumbs", @"Preview");
                //string folder = row["Folder"].ToString().Replace("@", "_").Replace(".", "_");
                string folder = row["Folder"].ToString();//.Replace("@", "_").Replace(".", "_");


                strTarget = string.Format(@"{0}\Favorites_{1}\{2}", txtHiResTarget.Text, row["MainEventCode"] as string, folder);
                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(strTarget))
                {
                    // create the directory
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(strTarget);
                }
                string destFileName = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", strTarget, row["ImageName"] as string);
                string sourceFileName = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", txtEventsDrive.Text, path);
                sourceFileName = sourceFileName.Replace(@"/", @"\");
                sourceFileName = sourceFileName.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
                try
                {
                    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName,true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    strError.AppendFormat("{0}{1}{1}", ex.Message, clr);
                }
            }
            //DirectoryInfo dir3 = new DirectoryInfo(strTarget);
            //txtImagesCopied.Text = Convert.ToString(dir3.GetFiles("*.jpg").Length);
            //strError.AppendFormat("Images in destination: {0}{1}{1}", txtImagesCopied.Text, clr);
            strError.AppendFormat("Time Ended: {0}{1}{1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), clr);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return strError.ToString();


    }
    private string CopyImages()
    {
        StringBuilder strError = new StringBuilder();
        string clr = "\r\n";
        strError.AppendFormat("Time started: {0}{1}{1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), clr);
        try
        {

            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.AppendFormat("SELECT FavoritesHeader.EmailAddress, MainEvents.MainEventCode, FavoritesDetail.ImagePath, ");
            str.AppendFormat("FavoritesDetail.ImageName FROM (FavoritesHeader LEFT JOIN FavoritesDetail ON ");
            str.AppendFormat("FavoritesHeader.FavoritesHeaderID = FavoritesDetail.FavoritesHeaderID) INNER JOIN ");
            str.AppendFormat(" MainEvents ON FavoritesHeader.MainEventID = MainEvents.MainEventID WHERE ");
            str.AppendFormat(" FavoritesHeader.EmailAddress='{0}' AND MainEvents.isActive=1", txtEmail.Text);

            DataTable dt_Images = GetDataTable(str.ToString());
            int maxFiles = dt_Images.Rows.Count;

            strError.AppendFormat("Images to copy: {0}{1}{1}", maxFiles, clr);
            Application.DoEvents();


            progressBar.Maximum = maxFiles;
            progressBar.Value = 0;
            ProgressPanel.Visible = true;


            string strTarget = string.Empty;
            int i = 0;
            int AlreadyExists = -1;
            int ExistsIndex = 0;

            foreach (DataRow row in dt_Images.Rows)
            {
                i = i + 1;
                progressBar.Value = i;

                ProgressCount.Text = string.Format("Files Copied: {0} of {1}", i, maxFiles);
                Application.DoEvents();

                string path = row["ImagePath"] as string;
                path = path.Replace(@"Thumbs", @"HiRes");
                string eMail = txtEmail.Text.ToString().Replace("@", "_").Replace(".", "_");

                strTarget = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}_MainEvent\FavoriteCD\{2}", txtHiResTarget.Text, row["MainEventCode"] as string, eMail);
                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(strTarget))
                {
                    // create the directory
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(strTarget);
                }
                string destFileName = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", strTarget, row["ImageName"] as string);
                string sourceFileName = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", txtEventsDrive.Text, path);
                sourceFileName = sourceFileName.Replace(@"/", @"\");
                //sourceFileName = sourceFileName.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
                try
                {
                    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    AlreadyExists = (strError.ToString()).IndexOf("already exists");
                    if (AlreadyExists == -1)
                    {
                        strError.AppendFormat("{0}{1}{1}", ex.Message, clr);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ExistsIndex = ExistsIndex + AlreadyExists;
                    }

                }
            }

            if (ExistsIndex > 0)
            {
                strError.AppendFormat("Some files were copied previously{0}", clr);
            }

            DirectoryInfo dir3 = new DirectoryInfo(strTarget);
            txtImagesCopied.Text = Convert.ToString(dir3.GetFiles("*.jpg").Length);
            strError.AppendFormat("Images in destination: {0}{1}{1}", txtImagesCopied.Text, clr);
            strError.AppendFormat("Time Ended: {0}{1}{1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), clr);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return strError.ToString();


    }

    private void UpdateDatabase(string sql)
    {
        OleDbConnection sqlConnNew = new OleDbConnection();
        sqlConnNew.ConnectionString = oleDbConnection1.ConnectionString;

        sqlConnNew.Open();

        OleDbCommand oleCMD = new OleDbCommand();
        oleCMD.Connection = sqlConnNew;
        OleDbTransaction oleTrans = oleCMD.Connection.BeginTransaction();
        oleCMD.Transaction = oleTrans;
        oleCMD.CommandText = sql;
        try
        {
            oleCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
            oleTrans.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        oleCMD.Connection.Close();
        oleCMD.Dispose();
    }
    public DataTable GetDataTable(string sql)
    {
        DataTable RS = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection sqlConnNew = new OleDbConnection();
            sqlConnNew.ConnectionString = oleDbConnection1.ConnectionString;

            sqlConnNew.Open();

            OleDbCommand oleCMD = new OleDbCommand(sql, sqlConnNew);
            OleDbDataAdapter oleAdr = new OleDbDataAdapter(oleCMD);
            oleAdr.AcceptChangesDuringFill = true;
            oleAdr.Fill(RS);
            oleCMD.Connection.Close();
            oleCMD.Dispose();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        return RS;
    }

    private void SaveDefaults_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // get the application path to find the ini file
            string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
            IniFile ini = new IniFile(string.Format(@"{0}\gift.ini", appPath));

            ini.IniWriteValue("Info", "LocationOfEvents", txtEventsDrive.Text);
            ini.IniWriteValue("Info", "FavWorkSpace", txtHiResTarget.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Defaults settings have been saved.", "Save Defaults");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    private void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void About_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AboutBox MyAboutBox = new AboutBox();
        MyAboutBox.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void getInvoiceToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        GetInvoice getInvoice = new GetInvoice();
        getInvoice.ShowDialog();

    }

    private void processImagesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        ProcessImages processImages = new ProcessImages();
        processImages.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblLoadingData.Visible = true;
        this.gryFavoritesListTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsFavoritesList.gryFavoritesList);
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }




    private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataView dv = new DataView(this.dsFavoritesList.gryFavoritesList);
        dv.Sort = "Name ASC";

        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'",txtSearch.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;


        //if (index == -1)
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show("No PK matches " + txtSearch.Text);
        //}
        //else
        //{


        //    dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = index;
        //    dataGridView1.Refresh();
        //    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGrid.Rows[index].Cells[0];
        //    dataGridView1.Rows[index].Selected = true;

            //dataGridView1.CurrentRowIndex = intRow;                
            //dataGridView1.Select(intRow);
       //}


    }

    private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.MdiParent.MainMenuStrip.Enabled = false;

        try
        {
            string strError = CopyAllImages();

            MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
            MessageBox.Show(this, strError, "Copy All Favorites", buttons, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

            ProgressPanel.Visible = false;
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.MdiParent.MainMenuStrip.Enabled = true;
        }

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.gryFavoritesListTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsFavoritesList.gryFavoritesList);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblLoadingData.Visible = false;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: can you give us the code where for the selection as well? ... after reading again you don't know where you select it ... can you post the hole file?

Comment: I posted the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

validated test to handle the event instead of the TextBox TextChanged event, because every time you insert a character is called the event, while you search with the Validated when actually carried out the validation of txtsearch.

```
private void txtSearch_Vlidated(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

{

```
 DataView dv = new DataView(this.dsFavoritesList.gryFavoritesList);
 dv.Sort = "Name ASC";

 dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'",txtSearch.Text);
 dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
```

}

Regards.

Comment: I like having the rows sorted after typing each letter.  But this doesn't answer my question about the selection